# Can file be stored on Azure cosmos db for vertex attached with an attribute?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have generated graph on Azure cosmos db using gremlin queries from my web application. But while generating the Vertex if i want to attach an image or some document file to that vertex then can it be added. Since now I am able to only add properties to the vertex.

Any suggestion for this newbie on how I can store files on azure Cosmos db and store a link to that files on the related vertex ?

Answer (score 1):

> while generating the Vertex if i want to attach an image or some document file to that vertex then can it be added. Since now I am able to only add properties to the vertex.

As you said, in [Azure Cosmos DB: Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction) we can only add **properties** to express information about the **vertices** and **edges**.

For your requirement(attaching images or some document files), you can try to store the images or document files in  external storage, such as [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-introduction), and then you can store URL of images or document files in property.

Comment: Thanks, Fred Han.